# withSpinner not showing repeatedly when using uiOutput in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Please help me to show spinner repeatedly when reactive value appear (when click action button)

### UI.R

```
library(shinycssloaders)
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 2, actionButton("actButton", "Click")),
    column(width = 6, withSpinner(uiOutput("htmlExample")))
  )
)
```

### SERVER.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinycssloaders)

server<-function(input, output)
{
  getRandomNumber <- function() {
    Sys.sleep(1)
    randamNumber <- runif(n = 1, min = 1e-12, max = .9999999999)
    return(HTML(paste0("<h1>Hai Render Html ................",
                       randamNumber, "<h1>")))
  }
  observeEvent(input$actButton,{
    if (input$actButton == 0)
      return(0)
    isolate({
      output$htmlExample <- renderUI({
        getRandomNumber()
      })
    })
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using `busyIndicator` form the package `shinysky` instead.

Here is an example code:

```
library(shinysky)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 2, actionButton("actButton", "Click")),
    busyIndicator(text = 'Rendering HTML....'),
    column(width = 6, uiOutput("htmlExample"))
  )
)

server<-function(input, output)
{
  getRandomNumber <- function() {
    Sys.sleep(2)
    randamNumber <- runif(n = 1, min = 1e-12, max = .9999999999)
    return(HTML(paste0("<h1>Hi Render Html ................",
                       randamNumber, "<h1>")))
  }
  observeEvent(input$actButton,{
    if (input$actButton == 0)
      return(0)
    isolate({
      output$htmlExample <- renderUI({
        getRandomNumber()
      })
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I am used withSpinner in my whole project. so i need solution for that. i really thank you for reply back

Comment: @S.Elavarasan, did you ever figure this out? Thanks.